# Cambiar color de app superior

Tags: flutter

tengo el siguiente problema, cambie el color superior e inferior de los appBar, con este codigo:

```
SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(
  statusBarColor: blueColor,
  systemNavigationBarColor: blueColor,
));
```

ahora tengo el problema que deseo cambiar el color de la fuente e iconos
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

a color blanco, como hago esto?

Answer (score 0):

si es flutter por qué no usas esto?

```
    import
    'package:flutter_statusbarcolor/flutter_statusbarcolor.dart';

    void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    FlutterStatusbarcolor.setStatusBarColor(Colors.white);
    return MaterialApp(
    title: app_title,
    theme: ThemeData(
    primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
    ),
    home: HomePage(title: home_title),
    );
     }
      }
```

Comment: me cambia el color de la barra pero no el color de la hora y los iconos y eso es lo que necesito que la barra me quede de ese color y letras y iconos en blanco!

Answer (score 0):

Podrías usar el `AnnotatedRegion` widget.

```dart
AnnotatedRegion<SystemUiOverlayStyle>(
      value: SystemUiOverlayStyle.light,
      child: TuWidget(),

)
```

Comment: No me funciono!

Comment: no cambia el color o te da algún error?

Comment: no cambia el color

Answer (score 0):

```
SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(
statusBarColor: blueColor,
systemNavigationBarColor: blueColor,
systemNavigationBarIconBrightness: Brightness.light,
statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.light
));
```

solo agrego el statusBarIconBrightness que es el brillo de los iconos de la barra de estado superior., en este caso requerías en blanco por ello se le pone Brightness.light si fuera el caso contrario seria Brightness.dark lo mismo para systemNavigationBarIconBrightness que son los brillo de los iconos de la barra de navegación del sistema.mas info en la documentación https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/SystemUiOverlayStyle-class.html