# Cambiar el color de la aplicación superior de Android Kotlin

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación usando Kotlin con webview, pero al ejecutar la aplicación, la barra superior obtiene el color a continuación:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aqui]

¿Cómo cambio a negro? He estado en temas.xml, he cambiado los colores en función de los colores.xml, pero no funcionó.

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.NameApp" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>
</resources>
```

Vi que tiene este enlace, pero no sé cómo aplicar en Kotlin. [Cambiar color de app superior](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/457050/cambiar-color-de-app-superior)

Perdona mi español.

Comment: Ese enlace no te sirve porque Flutter te permite desarrollar apps multiplataforma programadas en Dart. Kotlin y Java son los 2 lenguajes soportados oficialmente por Google para desarrollar apps de Android nativas.

Comment: Hola Mateo. Sí. En mi caso sería en Kotlin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El color de la barra de estatus se cambia con `colorPrimaryDark`, agrega este elemento a tu estilo:

```
   <style.....>
       ...
       ...
       <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#D1BCFF</item>
       ...
       ...
    </style>
```

Revisa esta imagen, te dará una idea de qué valor usar en cada caso:

[image: jorgesys style material design]